# Find string of decimal digits in Pi

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I am trying to find the first occurrence of "12345" in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ by using MySQL. Possibly by using the `Instr` function?

But I am stuck because it only displays the first 7 fractional digits.

Comment: Where did you get the value of pi?  What datatype is it stored in?

Comment: You might have done that yourself ...

Comment: @RickJames Actually I did that by SELECT PI()

Comment: It'd really help if any of you guys could get MyQL to print pi and then I'll use instr to find the first occurrence of 12345

Comment: PI() is good to only about 16 decimal places because it is stored in a `DOUBLE` datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USE test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pi;
CREATE TABLE pi
(
    num BLOB
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO pi VALUES
('3.14159265358...');
SELECT LOCATE('12345',num) FROM pi;
```

Here is the output

```
+---------------------+
| locate('12345',num) |
+---------------------+
|               49704 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

I had to go to http://www.piday.org/million/ and scroll/Ctrl-F dozens of times until my web browser found it. Then, I pasted about 60000 characters into that line. Then, I ran the code using MySQL 5.6.21 on my laptop in Windows 8.1.

Have Fun !!!

## UPDATE 2015-03-14 15:52 EST

BTW I just discovered this website : [**100,000 Digits of Pi**](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/%7Ehuberty/math5337/groupe/digits.html).

This displays pi to 100,000 digits instantly. `12345` is also there.

## UPDATE 2015-03-14 15:57 EST

I tried the [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) function

```
+--------------------+
| instr(num,'12345') |
+--------------------+
|              49704 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It works as well !!!

Comment: Happy Pi day. 3/14/15